# JQuery changing background color of unordered list item

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list and i would like to change the background color of each item when that item is selected(items in list are link tags) here is the JQuery code that I have so far.

```
$("#cat").focusin(function(){
    $("#cat").css("background-color", "#1796cf");
});

$("#cat").focusout(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#333333");
});
```

`#cat` is set as ID in the html for each item in my list. This works but only works on the first item in the unordered list. Please help me get this to work on every item in my list.

Comment: Use a class, IDs are meant to be *unique*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Id should be unique** use `class` instead of id

```
$(".cat").focusin(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#1796cf");
});

$(".cat").focusout(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#333333");
});
```

Comment: I tried this but changing it to a class makes it not work at all :(

Comment: Nevermind silly error on my part it definitely works! Sorry im a noob :( lol Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try another way

```
$('.cat').focus(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#1796cf");
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#333333");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

ok after your comment I've re-made my answer, here are the things you need in order to make it work:

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="selectable">
    <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.selectable li {
    background-color: #333;
}

.selectable li.cat {
    background-color: #1796cf;
}

.selectable li a {
    color: white;
}

.selectable > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

and finally some **JQuery** to do the magic:

```
$('.selectable > li > a').click( function( e ) {
    //prevent click from anchors, you can avoid this step if you need them
    e.preventDefault();
    //look for any previous class asigned
    $('.selectable').find('li').removeClass('cat');
    //add class to the li
    $(this).parent().addClass('cat');
});
```

link to the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w26b6w2/2/)

Comment: Your right this didn't work the way I wanted it to...my goal is to have the background color change for the selected link and then when a new link is clicked to have the first link change back to original color and new link change to selected color...any ideas on how to get this to work? RIght now I have an if/else statement set up with an onlick function being called but im not sure what selector I should use for selected link and it is always calling my else statement. Help?

Comment: now seems more likely to what you need, let me know your thoughts. Regards

Comment: this got me super close but how do i then change the color back to original color when another link is selected? It is changing the colors but not changing them back when u click on another link.

Comment: they should have a "default color" applied to .selectable > li, so when the class is added it's changed, and when removed it goes back to the original, I'll update the code